# Ruby and Mongo - how to query for a collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a database connection that I got like this:

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("app-development")
```

but when I tried querying for a collection like this:

```
@users = User.all.limit(50)
```

I got this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `users' for #<Mongo::DB:0x10ed5f3b8>):
```

My collection is called users. What was the right way to get that data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you've got the right case on users? is it 'Users' or 'users'?

you could try:

```
@users = users.find("").limit(1);
```

This is the resource I used to learn...
http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

Jim

Comment: That will return a ruby object containing the first document in the collection.  I don't understand cursors full enough yet to answer with confidence.  I've only been playing with this for a couple of days myself! - you should remove the ".pretty()" by the way, thats a shell command for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is this:

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("app-development")
```

becomes

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("app-development").collection("your_collection")
```

Then you will be acting on the database in the way you are imagining.